# iPad or iPhone doesn't charge until unlocked?

Tags: iphone, ipad, charging, unlock

When I plug my iPhone or iPad into my laptop with the USB cable, it doesn't start charging until I unlock the device with touch ID or code. Is there a way I can change this behavior? I don't think it used to work that way (years ago), and now I often forget to unlock it, so I think a device is charging and then hours later realize it's not.

To clarify, I don't have to leave it unlocked. I unlock it, then the battery icon changes to indicate it's charging, then I can lock/sleep it again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are observing is due to a security related change made in iOS 11.4.1.

- [Using USB accessories with iOS 11.4.1 and later](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208857)

> Starting with iOS 11.4.1, if you use USB accessories with your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or if you connect your device to a Mac or PC, you might need to unlock your device for it to recognize and use the accessory. Your accessory then remains connected, even if your device is subsequently locked.

This setting can be accessed on your iPhone/iPad by going to Settings app → Face ID & Passcode → USB Accessories.

> When the USB Accessories setting is off, as in the image above, you might need to unlock your iOS device to connect USB accessories.

This is turned off by default for security reasons. If you turn it on, your iPhone/iPad will start charging instantly, without unlocking it's connected to your laptop.

Comment: Thanks. Mmm... I wonder what the security issue is. It would be nice to only enable it only for my laptop, not any computer. Since I don't understand it the security issue, I may just leave it off.

Comment: @RobN when you plug your iphone into the computer, you allow that computer to see your camera roll. if you turn this off, then anytime you plug in your iphone the computer will immediately be able to see your pics, without any prompt on the iphone. now imagine if one of those public USB hubs at an airport was in fact a computer that tried to scrape images off peoples phones. your images would be scraped without you knowing. That is why the prompt is important.

Comment: @basher: That's not the case. Photos are not exposed to the computer connected unless you grant permission by unlocking. The update in question increased security further to not even interface with connected USB devices at all, to close off the attack surface that was being used by blackhat devices being sold to law enforcement and rogue nation state actors to access the contents of seized devices.

Comment: Okay, but nobody is asking to "recognize and use the accessory" (which it isn't, anyway), just to draw power, which doesn't require exposing any USB endpoints at all (yes, you need to connect to do power negotiation, but you don't need to offer up any useful interfaces in your descriptor or respond meaningfully to anything the host sends). This seems like a decision that *decreases* security by inconveniencing users until they turn security options off.

Comment: @hobbs Seems correct. If you imagine that the public USB charging station is an evil computer, you can't use it.

Comment: Also of note: there are charge-only USB-A passthrough dongles and USB/Lightning cables out there, where the only conductors present are the power supply ones. Since the device can’t make a connection on any of the other pins, it’ll just charge without security warnings.

Comment: @hobbs You can't just start drawing power from USB host. You need to negotiate how much power is available first. (Ok, you can draw 0.5W - which is nearly useless for charging)

Comment: @Agent_L you might have wanted to read my comment all the way to the end.

Comment: @hobbs I did. You're proposing to communicate with the computer to negotiate power, but also to not communicate with it when it's trying to hack you over this very negotiation. Eat the cookie and have the cookie. Computer is not a charger so it doesn't expose charger-type "negotiation" by shorting data pins (no USB device would work then). What you need is exactly to "recognize and use the accessory". Or use a dumb charger, computer can't charge as fast anyway. The main point is : computer is not a charger. There is no point of connecting iPhone to it other than data transfer.

Comment: Except a computer is implicitly also a charger when there's a powered USB hub between the device and the computer.  USB is dumb and insecure, but it's what there is.  Unlocking the device to allow power negotiation _is_ less secure than doing power negotiation without unlocking the device, unless of course your USB code is riddled with bugs.

Comment: Ideally the device should offer two options when it senses that it's connected to a port that seems to be a computer instead of just a charger:  1) start charging; or 2) unlock and allow full access.